# Getting none when extracting images with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

This is the Html code

```
  <div class="image-frame"><img alt="Figure 2, CT - noncontrast" data-action="zoom" class="" ng-click="zoomClick($event)" role="button" tabindex="0" ng-src="/images/full/synpic100378.jpg" src="/images/full/synpic100378.jpg">   </div>
```

This is the previous code for context

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_class_name('next')
    if 'inactive' in elm.get_attribute('class'):
       break;
#inserts Image details into dataframe
h1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name('image-details').text
print(h1)`
```

This line returns none when it should return an image

```
#insert image into data frame
**img =driver.find_element_by_class_name("image-frame").get_attribute("src")**
```

Comment: aren't the class names different in your examples?

Comment: Try to be a little more verbose by posting a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. _This line returns none when it should return an image_ Why is that? In the HTML you shared, the element with `class` `image-frame` doesn't seem to have a `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `find_element_by_class_name()` is returning the `<div>` tag, not the `<img>` tag. The div tag has no `src` attribute, so it returns None.

You may want to try `find_element_by_css_selector()` or `find_element_by_xpath()` to find the img tag.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using find_element_by_xpath and that got me what I needed.